# MediaWiki - How to do a hard redirect?

Tags: url, redirect, mediawiki, wiki

I need to redirect to another article, as soon as i get to a page. In other words: the URL needs to change to the original article. How do i do that?

```
www.myWiki.org/RD
```

should e.g. jump to

```
www.myWiki.org/redirect
```

As soon as the user gets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Page `[[RD]]` write this:

```
#REDIRECT [[redirect]]
```

And than `www.myWiki.org/RD` gets hard redirected to `www.myWiki.org/redirect`.

This works on current Mediawiki versions, in older versions you will get a soft redirect. 
More on [mediawiki.org Help:Redirects](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Redirects)